# Filtering results of a join between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not even sure how to title this question or how to look for similar questions for what I am trying to achieve.

I am working with two tables. The first one contains the relations between 2 other tables.

Table doc_companies

```
idDoc   idCompany   contact
  1         2          1
  1         5          1
  1         6          1
  1         6          3
```

idDoc is the id of a document that will be addressed to different contacts located at different companies. The thing confusing me is that the fields idCompany and contact are in the same table.

This is the table companies

```
id      name1       email1          name2       email2          name3       email3
2       John        john@mail.com   Jack        jack@mail.com   Jane        jane@mail.com
5       Susan       susan@mail.com  Pete        pete@mail.com   Mary        mary@mail.com
6       Lily        lily@mail.com   Bob         bob@mail.com    Tom         tom@mail.com
```

So I need to get the numbers from the contacts column and then get the data from
table companies using something like "name"+contact

So considering the first table. This is the result I want to get to with my query if idDoc = 1

```
name        email
John        john@mail.com
Susan       susan@mail.com
Lily        lily@mail.com
Tom         tom@mail.com
```

I do not know how to start with a query like that. My first thought was a inner join between tables and I came up with this:

```
SELECT companies.name1, companies.email1, companies.name2, companies.email2, companies.name3, companies.email.3
FROM companies
INNER JOIN doc_company
ON companies.id = doc_companies.idCompany
WHERE doc_companies.idDoc = 1
```

But this returns all the contacts and six columns.

How can I get the result I need? Maybe use subqueries?

Comment: Looks like your `companies` table needs to be atomised/normalised.

Comment: @Terry That's what I thought, but I need to know if there's a way to make it work. If it's impossible then I'll inform my supervisor that the database needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE dc.contact
         WHEN 1 THEN c.name1
         WHEN 2 THEN c.name2
         WHEN 3 THEN c.name3
       END name  
     , CASE dc.contact
         WHEN 1 THEN c.email1
         WHEN 2 THEN c.email2
         WHEN 3 THEN c.email3
       END email
  FROM companies c
    INNER JOIN doc_company dc
      ON c.id = dc.idCompany
  WHERE dc.idDoc = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `UNION` query in a derived table with an outer `WHERE` filter:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
   (SELECT d.idDoc, c.name1 as `name`, c.email1 as `email`
    FROM companies c
    INNER JOIN doc_company d
           ON c.id = d.idCompany
    UNION 
    SELECT d.idDoc, c.name2, c.email2 
    FROM companies c
    INNER JOIN doc_company d
           ON c.id = d.idCompany
    UNION
    SELECT d.idDoc, c.name3, c.email3
    FROM companies c
    INNER JOIN doc_company d
           ON c.id = d.idCompany
    ) t
WHERE t.idDoc = 1
```

*And yes, have that talk with supervisor on database design as you can see queries and storage are more complex and less efficient and less scalable.*

Comment: For some reason it adds a blank row in the result table. I decided to go with the other answer since it's shorter, but I really appreciate yout help.